# Oracle SQL script - passing a parameter

Tags: oracle, delete, parameter

I have an Oracle SQL script like this:

```
delete FROM activ_princ where id in
    (select ap.id FROM activ_princ ap
        inner join sect e on e.id=ap.FK_ID_SECTIUNE_e
        inner join chest ch on ch.id=e.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
    WHERE ch.id=1661);
delete FROM activ_sec where id in
    (select asec.id FROM activ_sec asec
        inner join sect e on e.id=asec.FK_ID_SECTIUNE_e
        inner join chest ch on ch.id=e.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
    WHERE ch.id=1661);
delete FROM sect where id in
    (select e.id FROM sect e
        inner join chest ch on ch.id=e.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
    WHERE ch.id=1661);
```

how can I pass 1661 as a parameter and execute all the script changing just the id I want to delete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQLPlus, you can use a variable & it will prompt you.

```
delete FROM activ_princ where id in
    (select ap.id FROM activ_princ ap
        inner join sect e on e.id=ap.FK_ID_SECTIUNE_e
        inner join chest ch on ch.id=e.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
    WHERE ch.id=&1);
delete FROM activ_sec where id in
    (select asec.id FROM activ_sec asec
        inner join sect e on e.id=asec.FK_ID_SECTIUNE_e
        inner join chest ch on ch.id=e.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
    WHERE ch.id=&1);
delete FROM sect where id in
    (select e.id FROM sect e
        inner join chest ch on ch.id=e.FK_ID_CHESTIONAR
    WHERE ch.id=&1);
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIIEDF).